# Android Studio Code Aligning Does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am following a video tutorial. On tutor's pc these two textviews align properly but not on mine. Please let me know whats wrong with that. -image attached- . Thank you.

[image: A studio image]

Comment: show your layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

When using constraint layout, you need to provide some constraint to it.
Here to second TextView add:

```
layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/text_view_1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and use

```
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to align texts, but you are trying to achieve this by using a Constraint Layout which is a bit complex.

Here is an example using a Relative Layout with `android:layout_toEndOf=""`, it is simply used to push your TextView at the end of your desired Textview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="FIRST TEXT" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/firstText"
            android:text="SECOND TEXT"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```